# Configuring a SSRS Data Driven Subscription to run on multiple CRM records

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm

I have a report that takes a single crm record as a parameter and I would like to configure a data-driven subscription for it such that each time this subscription runs it produces multiple PDF files, one for each record returned in the parameter query. I noticed that when the subscription runs it produces multiple PDFs, but only the first of the parameter results is used. Is there a workaround for this behavior?

Comment: Probably more details are needed about what purpose the parameter serves and what you mean by only the first result is used, but a shot in the dark would be maybe a wrapper report that iterates through all the parameter results, and a sub-report that is instantiated by each of them.

Comment: The parameter is the set of all columns corresponding to a single crm record. I tested the subscription out by first entering a parameter query that returned one row, i.e. one record, which worked. Now that I have expanded the query to return multiple rows, the subscription is simply exporting multiple PDF versions of the report, all of which used the first row of the parameter query to populate the report data.

Comment: How does the parameter get used by the sql that generates the report data?